# Why are phrases/chord progressions most commonly four bars?

Tags: chord-progressions

Chord progression and phrases are almost always 4 bars (in pop and country). Why is this? Why not 8 bars(I-I-IV-IV-V-V-I-I)

Comment: Singers' lung capacities aren't large enough?

Comment: I think there must be plenty of songs with an 8-bar repeating chord progression, and lots of riff-based songs have a 2-bar repeating pattern. "almost always 4 bars" doesn't ring true to me - does that come from a study/corpus analysis?

Comment: Perhaps the **12-bar** blues might explain a little of this tendency. Note how you cannot split that into a whole number of 8-bar phrases.

Comment: @topo Just type in guitar chord progressions they are all 4 bars. Listen to the radio.